# How to make form inputs side by side and with only one label? CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using the following code to  generate a form.

```
echo $this->Form->create('External');
echo $this->Form->input('program_title', array('label' => 'Program Name'));
echo $this->Form->input('reference_code', array('label' => 'Reference No.'));
echo $this->Form->input('date_received', array('label' => 'Date Received', 'type' => 'date'));
echo $this->Form->input('date_released', array('value' => date('Y-m-d'), 'type' => 'hidden'));
echo $this->Form->input('inclusive_date_start', array('label' => 'Inclusive Date Start', 'type' => 'date'));
echo $this->Form->input('inclusive_date_end', array('label' => 'Inclusive Date End', 'type' => 'date'));
echo $this->Form->input('time_start', array('label' => 'Time Start', 'type' => 'time'));
echo $this->Form->input('time_end', array('label' => 'Time End', 'type' => 'time'));
echo $this->Form->end('Add Program');
```

And it creates the following:

[image: Original Image]

How do I make it show up like this one instead?

[image: Edited Image]

The second image was just edited so I can show you how I want it to look like. Care to shed some light?

Answer (score 0):

Within CakePHP, you don't always have to include a label for your form elements, allowing you to do custom groupings and positions.

Here is a quick example of how you can do it with your code.  For simplicity, I kept everything inside of PHP, but you can break out of PHP and write the actual HTML as well.  Please note the use of `'label' => false`

```
echo $this->Form->create('External');
echo $this->Form->input('program_title', array('label' => 'Program Name'));
echo $this->Form->input('reference_code', array('label' => 'Reference No.'));
echo $this->Form->input('date_received', array('label' => 'Date Received', 'type' => 'date'));
echo $this->Form->input('date_released', array('value' => date('Y-m-d'), 'type' => 'hidden'));
//Custom HTML code
echo '<div>Inclusive Date</div>';
echo '<div>';
echo '<div style="float: left;">
echo $this->Form->input('inclusive_date_start', array('label' => false, 'type' => 'date'));
echo '</div>';
echo '<div style="float: left;">-</div>';
echo '<div style="float: left;">';
echo $this->Form->input('inclusive_date_end', array('label' => false, 'type' => 'date'));
echo '</div>'
echo '<div style="clear: both;"></div>';
echo '</div>';
//Back to normal PHP
echo $this->Form->input('time_start', array('label' => 'Time Start', 'type' => 'time'));
echo $this->Form->input('time_end', array('label' => 'Time End', 'type' => 'time'));
echo $this->Form->end('Add Program');
```